# Django admin to display localised date format

Tags: django, date, django-admin, format

I live in New Zealand and the date format is DD/MM/YYYY, however the date field in admin shows YYYY-MM-DD, I have tried changing the widget by:

```
    formfield_overrides = { 
        models.DateField: {'widget': widgets.DateInput},
    }
```

Since from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput):

```
DateInput
class DateInput
Date input as a simple text box: <input type='text' ...>

Takes same arguments as TextInput, with one more optional argument:

format
The format in which this field’s initial value will be displayed.

If no format argument is provided, the default format is the first format found in DATE_INPUT_FORMATS and respects Format localization.
```

Also in my settings:

```
USE_I18N = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Pacific/Auckland'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-NZ' # or en-nz? both don't work
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d')
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` in `settings.py` are only respected when `USE_I18N = False`

If you have `USE_I18N = True` you need to use `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` also and create some format module files, as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#format-module-path

Comment: Got it working now, for anyone is having the same problem, please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297299/django-format-module-path-not-working/21322417#21322417

Comment: fixed... Django 1.3 is so old and deprecated they've taken the docs offline it seems :)