# django FORMAT_MODULE_PATH not working

Tags: django, format, locale

Base on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295721/django-admin-to-display-localised-date-format) and [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#format-module-path)

I have created a format structure

```
  mysite
    |
    mysite
    ├── en_NZ # I also tried en_NZ.UTF-8
    │   ├── formats.py
    │   ├── formats.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __init__.pyc
```

which formats.py looks like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
```

and in settings.py:

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'mysite.formats'
```

my locale information on my server is:

```
$locale
LANG=en_NZ.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_NZ.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

but the date string in admin still in YYYY-MM-DD format, any ideas?

Comment: Then why link to the documentation for version 1.3? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#format-module-path

Comment: @crazyzubr well OK, my mistake, but the documentation for this is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually consulting the formats, I just needed to add 2 more settings to the formats.py

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d')
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```