# Django localize=True doesn't work on DateTimeField

Tags: django, localization

In New Zealand we input date time in this format: `%d/%m/%Y`

I have this model field:

```
entry_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Based on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#enabling-localization-of-fields), I added to the model form:

```
class Meta:
    localized_fields = ('entry_start_date',)
```

My settings are:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Pacific/Auckland'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-nz'
USE_I18N = True
```

Some how the form is still complaining about incorrect date/time format on '22/11/2015', but worked using '2015-11-22'.

But if I change DateTimeField to DateField, worked on '22/11/2015'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran out of options but used the custom formats approach that I did before:

[django FORMAT_MODULE_PATH not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297299/django-format-module-path-not-working)

To make it work, I had to add '%d/%m/%Y' into DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import absolute_import

DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d')
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y')
```